# Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined when calling subcribe on function

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm working with a jwt token and I need to know the role of the user to decide which routing is allowed on the client side and which menu I show in the navbar.

All of this is saved in a service which should tell the app-routing module if the user is allowed to access this route and the navbar if it should show the menu.

Here is the existing solution which works:

*security.service.ts*

```
import { ApplicationRef, EventEmitter, Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from "rxjs";
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from "@angular/router";
import { LoggingUtil } from "../utils/logging.util";
import { ServerUtil } from "../utils/server.util";
import { UserRoleModel } from "../model/models-generated";
import { Log } from "@angular/core/testing/src/logger";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SecurityService {

  constructor(private client: HttpClient) {}

  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    if (next.data.permission.includes(SecurityService.AVA_PERMISSION)) {
      this.getUserRoles().subscribe((result) => {
        return of(result.hasAvaRole);
      });
    } else if (next.data.permission.includes(SecurityService.ADMIN_PERMISSION)) {
      this.getUserRoles().subscribe((result) => {
        return of(result.hasAdminRole);
      });
    } else if (next.data.permission.includes(SecurityService.USER_PERMISSION)) {
      this.getUserRoles().subscribe((result) => {
        return of(result.hasUserRole);
      });
    }
    return of(false);
  }



  public getUserRoles(): Observable<UserRoleModel> {
    let serverUrl = ServerUtil.GetRestApiURL() + '/role';
    return this.client.get<UserRoleModel>(serverUrl);
  }
```

*navbar.component.ts*

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {SecurityService} from "../../services/security.service";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: "./navbar.component.html",
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  isAdmin: boolean;

  constructor(private securityService: SecurityService) {}


  ngOnInit() { 
    this.securityService.getUserRoles().subscribe(value => {
      this.isAdmin = value.hasAdminRole;
    })
  }
}
```

The problem with this version is that *canActivate()* will called at every route changes and therefore *getUserRoles()* too.

My goal was to do that you could either do it the old way or store the value. The switch is done with the helps of a spring profile, therefore I changed the code as following:

*security.service.ts*

```
export class SecurityService {
  hasAvaRole = false;
  hasAdminRole = false;
  hasUserRole = false;
  profiles: string[] = [];
  profileLoaded = false;

  // previously getUserRoles
  loadRoles(): Observable<UserRoleModel> {
    let serverUrl = ServerUtil.GetRestApiURL() + '/' + this.ACTION_PATH;
    LoggingUtil.debug("posting to remote server : " + serverUrl);
    return this.client.get<UserRoleModel>(serverUrl);
  }

  loadProfiles(): Observable<string[]> {
    let serverUrl = ServerUtil.GetRestApiURL() + '/' + this.PROFILE_PATH;
    LoggingUtil.debug("calling remote server : " + serverUrl);
    LoggingUtil.debug('client info :');
    console.log(this.client);
    return this.client.post<string[]>(serverUrl, null);
  }

  private getUserRolesSync(): UserRoleModel {
    return {'hasAvaRole': this.hasAvaRole, 'hasAdminRole': this.hasAdminRole, 'hasUserRole': this.hasUserRole}
  }


  getUserRoles(): Observable<UserRoleModel> {
     // if roles aren't in memory we load them
    if (!this.profileLoaded) {
      this.loadProfiles().subscribe((profiles: string[]) => {
        this.profiles = profiles;
        this.profileLoaded = true;
        if (this.profiles.includes('saving-role')) {
          this.loadRoles().subscribe(result => {
            this.hasAvaRole = result.hasAvaRole;
            this.hasAdminRole = result.hasAdminRole;
            this.hasUserRole = result.hasUserRole;
            return of(this.getUserRolesSync());
          });
        } else {
          return this.loadRoles();
        }
      });
    } else {
      if (this.profiles.includes('saving-role')) {
        return of(this.getUserRolesSync());
      } else {
        return this.loadRoles();
      }
    }
```

At first I thought that the httpClient wasn't injected but by printing it I saw that it wasn't the case. The spring profiles is properly loaded as well.

I now get the error "Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined" in navbar.component.ts at the line where I subscribe to the function

Comment: When `(this.profiles.includes('saving-role'))` you're not returning anything.

Comment: I might be missing something, but I can't find a `isAdmin` method in the code you've posted her, which would explain why it's undefined when trying to subscribe to it.

Comment: Where is your `isAdmin` function?

Comment: In the error stacktrace, check which file is the error pointing to.

Comment: @martin you mean that the return should be outside from the subscribe function ? If I do that won't it just return before the value are set ?

Comment: @sorry for the isAdmin, I removed it to reduce file size, it was the same method as getUserRoles()

Comment: @SiddAjmera the error is in navbar.component.ts at  `this.securityService.getUserRoles().subscribe()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here in the `getUserRoles`. If the user goes to the first `if` condition, then the control will go inside a `subscribe` block. But you haven't returned anything from there. So you'll have to `return` from there. And instead of `subscribe`ing, you'll have to `pipe` and `switchMap` to switch the context to the inner Observable:

```
getUserRoles(): Observable < UserRoleModel > {
  // if roles aren't in memory we load them
  if (!this.profileLoaded) {
    return this.loadProfiles().pipe(
      switchMap(profiles: string[]) => {
        this.profiles = profiles;
        this.profileLoaded = true;
        if (this.profiles.includes('saving-role')) {
          this.loadRoles().pipe(
            switchMap(result => {
              this.hasAvaRole = result.hasAvaRole;
              this.hasAdminRole = result.hasAdminRole;
              this.hasUserRole = result.hasUserRole;
              return of(this.getUserRolesSync());
            })
          );
        } else {
          return this.loadRoles();
        }
      })
    );
  }
  else {
    if (this.profiles.includes('saving-role')) {
      return of(this.getUserRolesSync());
    } else {
      return this.loadRoles();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help I didn't know about switchmap. I just had to put a return in front of `this.loadRoles().pipe(` for it to works.